Does the Leech lattice predict the genus $70$ of the buckyball surface?
In "Symplectization, Complexification and Mathematical Trinities" by V. Arnold, he came up with various trinities, one of which being the three Platonic symmetry groups $T,O,I$ of order $12, 24, 60$, respectively. These can be connected to the  projective special linear groups $\operatorname{PSL}(2,5),\,\operatorname{PSL}(2,7),\,\operatorname{PSL}(2,11)$ which have orders,
\begin{align}
5\times12 &= 60\\
7\times24 &= 168\\
11\times60 &= 660
\end{align}
These in turn are the orders of the icosahedron, Klein quartic, and buckyball surface ("From biplanes to the Klein quartic and the Buckyball", 2008). In page 12, using the Riemann-Hurwitz formula for $2g-2$, then,
\begin{align}
2\times\color{blue}0-2 &=60\left(1-\frac12-\frac13-\frac1{5}\right)\\
2\times\color{blue}3-2 &=168\left(1-\frac12-\frac13-\frac1{7}\right)\\ 
2\times\color{blue}{70}-2 &=660\left(1-\frac12-\frac15-\frac1{11}\right) 
\end{align}
which gives their genus as $g=0,3,70$, respectively. The "jump" to the integer $70$ seems a bit curious, but that number does appear in the Leech lattice. Also, recall that,
\begin{align}
1^3+2^3 &= 3^2\\
1^2+2^2+\dots+24^2 &= 70^2
\end{align}
the first appearing in Catalan's conjecture and the second in the cannonball problem.

Question: Is the fact that the buckyball surface has genus $70$ connected to the Weyl vector $(0,1,2,\dots,24; 70)$ of the Leech lattice, or is it just coincidence?

Update: Given Ramanujan's $\tau(n)$ function, I'd almost forgotten about this 2014 MO post where McKay and Yang-Hui observed two of the following congruences,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{24}\tau(n)^2 &\equiv 42 \;\; (\mathrm{mod} \;70)\\
\sum_{n=1}^{24}a(n)^2 &\equiv 42 \;\; (\mathrm{mod} \;70)\\
\sum_{n=1}^{24}b(n)^2 &\equiv 42 \;\; (\mathrm{mod} \;70)\\
\sum_{n=1}^{24}c(n)^2 &\equiv 42 \;\; (\mathrm{mod} \;70)
\end{align}
where $a(n), b(n), c(n)$ are the first $24$ coefficients of certain well-known modular functions (including the j-function) defined in that post.

It is apparently the case that, $$\sum_{n=1}^{24}n^{2p} \equiv 0 ;; (\mathrm{mod} ;70^2)$$ for $p=1$ and all primes $p>3$. See also this related MO post.
